# javascript using forEach for nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a `nested array` as follows:

```
var attendees={attendees :[{name: John},{name: Terry}]}
```

how do I loop through the names using the `forEach` function? I have tried:

```
attendees.forEach(function(attendees){
    console.log(attendees.name):
});
```

but it does not loop through the subarrays and just gives me:

```
[{name: John},{name: Terry}]
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: it should be `attendees.attendees.forEach`. The first is an object with a property `attendees` which is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With another foreach when detects is an array:

```
attendees.forEach(function(attendee){
   if(attendee.isArray()) {
      attendee.forEach(function(subattendee) {
         console.log(subattendee):
      });
   }
});
```

Be carefull with the nested variable. You have the same name for de readed array and for the function asigned variable.

Good luck

Comment: This works! With the following amendment: if(Array.isArray(attendee))

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this :

```
var attendees={
attendees : [
    { name: 'John'},
    { name: 'Terry'}
]};



attendees.attendees.forEach(function(attendees){console.log(attendees.name);});
```

Comment: hmmm when I try 'attendees.attendees.forEach(function(attendees)' I get: 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' error and when I try 'if (attendee.isArray())' I get an 'undefined is not a function' error